# Ajax html code output (unordered list) from XML not appended in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I created an XML file to store items for use in my unordered list and access it via Ajax call on page load. The problem is, the AJAX result is not appending in my div element. I copied the resulting HTML code from the Ajax call and pasted it in a div and it works fine, even displaying the children elements. I'm planning to do this until the 3rd level (grandchildren) but omitted the grandchildren section so i can tackle problems one at a time.

Here's my XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!-- this is a comment -->
<modules title="Modules" author="Gian Orpilla" createdDate="6/29/2016" modifiedBy="" modifiedDate="">
    <!-- *********** Parent 1 module ************--> <!-- TESTER FOR CLICKABLE GRANDCHILD AND CHILD-->
    <module name="Parent 1" icon="icon icon-display" h2="Parent 1 Tasks" link=""  li="icon icon-arrow-left" type="parent">
        <child name="Parent 1 Child 1" icon="icon icon-phone" h2="Parent 1 Child 1 Processes" link="" li="icon icon-arrow-left" type="child">
        </child>
        <child name="Parent 1 Child 2" icon="icon icon-tv" h2="" link="#" li="" type=""></child>
    </module>
    <!-- *********** Parent 1 module ************-->
    <!-- *********** Parent 2 module ************--> <!-- TESTER FOR CLICKABLE CHILD-->
    <module name="Parent 2" icon="icon icon-camera" h2="Parent 2 Tasks" link="" li="icon icon-arrow-left" type="parent">
          <child name="Parent 2 Child 1" icon="icon icon-shop" h2="Parent 2 Child 1 Processes" link="" li="" type=""></child>
          <child name="Parent 2 Child 2" icon="icon icon-diamond" h2="Parent 2 Child 2 Processes" link="" li="" type=""></child>
    </module>
    <!-- *********** Parent 2 module ************-->
    <!-- *********** Parent 3 module ************--> <!-- TESTER FOR 2 GRANDCHILD-->
    <module name="Parent 3" icon="icon icon-t-shirt" h2="Parent 3 Tasks" link="" li="icon icon-arrow-left" type="parent">
        <child name="Parent 3 Child 1" icon="icon icon-female" h2="Parent 3 Child 1 Processes" link=""  li="icon icon-arrow-left" type="child">
        </child>
        <child name="Parent 3 Child 2" icon="icon icon-male" h2="Parent 3 Child 2 Processes" link=""  li="icon icon-arrow-left" type="child">
        </child>
    </module>
    <!-- *********** Parent 3 module ************-->
    <!-- *********** Parent 4 module ************--> <!-- TESTER FOR CLICKABLE MODULE-->
    <module name="Parent 4" icon="icon icon-food" h2="" link="#"  li="" type=""></module>
    <!-- *********** Parent 4 module ************-->
</modules>
```

Below is my ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../ExternalPages/ListXML.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (xml) {
            var chunk = "<ul>"; //initiation of list

            $(xml).find('module').each(function () {

                //parent vars
                var li = $(this).attr('li');
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                var icon = $(this).attr('icon');
                var h2 = $(this).attr('h2');
                var link = $(this).attr('link');

                //child vars
                var li2;
                var name2;
                var icon2;
                var h22;
                var link2;

                //grandchild vars


                chunk = chunk + '<li class="' + li + '">' + //initiation of parent li and li class(if has child)
                    '<a class="' + icon + '" href="' + link + '">' + name + '</a>' + //inititation of parent link
                    '<div class="mp-level">' + '<h2 class="' + icon + '">' + h2 + '</h2>'; // initiation of header of child

                //start of child element
                if ($(this).attr('type')) {

                    chunk = chunk + '<ul>'; //initiation of child ul

                    $(this).find('child').each(function () {
                        //assigning to child values
                        li2 = $(this).attr('li');
                        name2 = $(this).attr('name');
                        icon2 = $(this).attr('icon');
                        h22 = $(this).attr('h2');
                        link2 = $(this).attr('link');

                        chunk = chunk + '<li class="' + li2 + '">' + //initiation of child li and li class(if has child)
                        '<a class="' + icon2 + '" href="' + link2 + '">' + name2 + '</a>' + //inititation of child link
                        '<div class="mp-level">' + '<h2 class="">' + h22 + '</h2>'; // initiation of header of grandchild
                        chunk = chunk + '</div></li>'; //ending of child li div mp-level
                    });

                    chunk = chunk + '</ul>'; //end of child ul
                }
                //end of child element

                chunk = chunk + '</div></li>'; //ending of parent li, div mp-level and child ul
            });

            chunk = chunk + '</ul>'; //ending of list

            $('#ListNav').append(chunk);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('oops');
        }
    });
```

This is the div located in the body:

```html
<div id="ListNav" class="mp-level">
     <h2 class="icon icon-world">All Modules</h2>
 </div>
```

This is the result of the ajax that I copy paste in the div which actually works. (spaced it out for easier understanding):

```html
<ul>
    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
        <a class="icon icon-display" href="">Parent 1</a>
        <div class="mp-level">
            <h2 class="icon icon-display">Parent 1 Tasks</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                    <a class="icon icon-phone" href="">P1 Child 1</a>
                    <div class="mp-level">
                        <h2 class="">P1 Child 1 Processes</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="icon icon-tv" href="#">P1 Child 2</a>
                    <div class="mp-level">
                        <h2 class=""></h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
        <a class="icon icon-camera" href="">Parent 2</a>
        <div class="mp-level">
            <h2 class="icon icon-camera">Parent 2 Tasks</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="icon icon-shop" href="">P2 Child 1</a>
                    <div class="mp-level">
                        <h2 class="">P2 Child 1 Processes</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="icon icon-diamond" href="">P2 Child 2</a>
                    <div class="mp-level">
                        <h2 class="">P2 Child 2 Processes</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
        <a class="icon icon-t-shirt" href="">Parent 3</a>
        <div class="mp-level">
            <h2 class="icon icon-t-shirt">Parent 3 Tasks</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                    <a class="icon icon-female" href="">P3 Child 1</a>
                    <div class="mp-level">
                        <h2 class="">P3 Child 1 Processes</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                    <a class="icon icon-male" href="">P3 Child 2</a>
                    <div class="mp-level">
                        <h2 class="">P3 Child 1 Processes</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a class="icon icon-food" href="#">Parent 4</a>
        <div class="mp-level">
            <h2 class="icon icon-food"></h2>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong but am not really sure what.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and the UL got populated and appended for me. If it's creating the html and just not appending may mean that it's not able to find the div.

Could you please try -

```
console.log($('#ListNav'));
```

to see if it's getting the Div?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I fixed the problem with the list issue by inverting the positions of the ' and ". I am now facing a different issue with regards to the UL not being recognized by my navigation javascript. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: No problems, if you are referring to a jquery navigation plugin, just try reinitializing the plugin after the append line. It should work because the DOM is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the back and forth comment of Rahul and I for the solution.